# Gunicorn Command Fails to run

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I cloned the github directory on my server from my github account. After activating the virtualenv and installing gunicorn.

I used this command to run this project on port 8001.

```
gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind www.example.com:8001
```

It shows me an error stating this :

```
[23123] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-09-29 10:52:37 +0000] [23123] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('www.example.com', 8001)
```

Can anyone tell the exact reason of this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't bind gunicorn to a domain, you bind it to an IP address. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Replacing domain name with IP address generates the same error and I was following this tutorial http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ to make my project run on port 8001.

Comment: Typically, your app will sit on the same server that's serving it. So you can bind to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1). If this is not the case, please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
gunicorn project_name.wsgi:application  --bind=example.com(your domain name):8001
```

You don't need to give the "www" .make sure in your settings.py ,debug="False"